# Code works fine in one workbook, but doesn't work in another, any solutions?

Tags: json, excel, vba, parsing, xml-parsing

Good Morning, recently someone sent me some a macro code to add to one of my workbooks. When I run the tool inside of the file that he sent me all works fine, with no errors. But when I import the module into my workbook, I get

> "Object does not support this property or method".

The error is at

```
Set parse = _ 
.parsejson
```

Basically the code grabs a jsonstring from a data pull, and then parses it through that function. The only thing I change is the sheet from Sheet1 -> Sheet6.

```
Dim hkey As Variant: Set http = parse(http.ResponseText).returnedObject.records
Public Function parse(json As String) As Object
With CreateObject("HTMLFile")
    With .parentWindow
         .execScript "var ParseJSON = " & json, "JScript": Set parse = _
         .ParseJson
    End With
End With
End Function
```

Comment: A thought:  see if the references are the same, comparing those in his versus your own workbooks

Comment: @John Hey john thanks for the response, I had done that before and even added those references to be top priority (over my already selected ones). But still nothing. Do you think my references could still be interacting with the newly added ones in a negative way?  Oddly  enough, it worked when I first imported the module, and then he gave me and updated one (that included something else) which didn't work, and when I went back to the original one, it didn't work.

Comment: That's not a reliable way to parse JSON in VBA.  You'd be much better off using this library:  https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Comment: @TimWilliams Hey tim, to fix my error I just recreated my entire macro, and it worked fine. But I must ask, why isn't this way ideal?

Comment: This approach will fail if your json object contains certain property names which do not play well in VBA, such as "count" or "length" for example.  Try it out...